# Data Reduction: How to understand this statement?

Tags: statistics

The statement is from Statistical inference written by george casella and roger l. berger.

I don't quite understand this statement: “An experimenter who uses only the observed value of the statistic, T(x), rather than the entire observed sample, x, will treat as equal two samples, x and y, that satisfy $T(x)=T(y)$ even though the actual sample values may be different from some ways.”

I am not sure if my understanding about the term statistic is correct, but so far, I interpret statistic as some property or characteristics a sample could potentially have, for example, if we sample 10 students from 100 students in total, then one statistic might be their average height, or in general, anything that is measurable will be regarded as a statistic of that sample.(Correct me if I am not correct)

What I don't understand about the above statement is that, it states two statistic T(x) and T(y) can be equal to each other even though the value of that sample is different, how is this possible? If the value of our measurement is not same from possibly two different two trials, but they have the same goal, how come these two things are equal to each other?

Comment: What's the mean of 2 and 2? What's the mean of 1 and 3?

Comment: That makes sense if we define the statistic to be the expected value, but is it always the case? What if we define the statistic to be other things, for example the highest student in class, in this case, clearly they must be the same in order to infer T(x) = T(y)? Or this is mainly based on how we define the statistic itself?